# Why is my input not working with my database?

Tags: javascript, html, sql

Why is my input not working with my database?
My prof. showed us an example of the code and I wrote it, like I need it for my website.
Sry for my bad english but I'm exhausted of solving the problem.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    var db = null;

    function openDB(){
        db = openDatabase('myfirstdb','1.0','dbsys',1*1024*1024);
    }

    function tabelleErzeugen(tx){
        console.log(tx);
        tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LogIn(benutzer,passwort)",[],SQLSuccess,SQLFail);
    } 
    function SQLSuccess(){
         console.log("erfolgreich");
    }

    function SQLFail(){
        console.log("nicht erfolgreich");
    }
    
    function addBenutzer(tx){
      let benutzer = document.getElementById('benutzer').value;
      let passwort = document.getElementById('passwort').value;
      tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO LogIn VALUES(benutzer,passwort)",[],SQLSuccess,SQLFail);
    }

    openDB();

    db.transaction(tabelleErzeugen);
  </script>
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div id="create">
      <h1>Datensatz hinzufügen</h1>
      <input type="text" id="benutzer" min="1" /><br />
      <input type="password" id="passwort" min="1" /><br />
      <input type="button" onclick="db.transaction(addBenutzer)" value="Kontakt speichern" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What kind of a database are you trying to use? Are you sure you need the DB in the browser?

Comment: The string `"INSERT INTO LogIn VALUES(benutzer,passwort)"` does not use the variables `benutzer` and `passwort`. Do you have something like prepared statements in your `tx` class? Is there documentation for the `tx` - class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [html5 web sql](http://www.w3big.com/en-US/html/html5-web-sql.html) for an example how to insert with dynamic values.
It should work like this:

```
tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO LogIn (benutzer,passwort) VALUES (?,?)",[benutzer, passwort],SQLSuccess,SQLFail);
```

Comment: Thank you man, everything works. But what are the questionmarks doing?

Comment: The question marks are being replaced by the values in the array that is the second argument to executeSql. This is safer than building the query string yourself, since it will automatically add quotes.